# How can I create a multiple clicking loop using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to create a clicking loop for the first row, but I've tried many ways to find the uniqueness of the HTML code, but it doesn't seem to work. As all of the CSS content is all have the same class.

Here is the link.
https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=mattress

[image]

Comment: all of then has `data-sqe="item"` so you can find all of them and later use `[:4]` to get only first row. BTW: but you have to keep urls as strings if you want to visit urls. If you will keep as `WebElements` then you loose them when you change page (when you click first link).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a class or an ID. You can use other attributes in tags.

You can get all items with attribute `data-sqe="item"` or even `data-sqe="link"`:

```
all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@data-sqe="link"]')
```

But the problem is that it doesn't load all links at once, but it adds them when you scroll the page. So you have to scroll it few times and it will load all elements. You can't scroll directly to the end of the page, because it may not load items which you skip (jump over).

```
for x in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,300)")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

After that you can get all URLs to the list. And later use `driver.get()` to load pages.

Better don't click when you get URLs in a loop, because it keeps only references to elements on the page (WebElement), not strings with URLs, and it will lose access to elements when you load another page.

```
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time
url = 'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=mattress'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

# Select language
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="language-selection__list"]/button').click()
time.sleep(3)

# Scroll few times to load all items
for x in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,300)")
    time.sleep(0.1)

# Get all links (without clicking)

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@data-sqe="link"]')
print('len:', len(all_items))

all_urls = []

for item in all_items:
    url = item.get_attribute('href')
    all_urls.append(url)
    print(url)

# Now use links

for item in all_urls:
    driver.get(url)
```